# CSS syntax and Javascript implementation for responsive height with scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have implemented this interface on this website `https://express-quiality-indicator.herokuapp.com/#/add-project`
As I have this long form, I want it to fit into my window using scrollbar. I implemented this using a css file:

```
form.add-project-form {
    height: 50 em;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

However, I found it un-compatible for computers of different screen size. I tested it with another computer, the form overflows and overlap with my menu navigation bar (You may see it on my link, and change the height property using dev tool).

Is there anyway to make it work on all screens? I tried using `height: calc(80%)` before but the scroll bar would fail, and the form would overflow my page.

Note my bottom menu used a was placed before add-project-from in html, but was forced to stay in the bottom of page using css:

```
nav.menu {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
height: auto;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

I found the style 'height: 50vh' useful to some extend, which automatically adjust the size of my form to 50% of the window height. A more responsive style may be implemented by javascript, which I will look into later.

Comment: are you looking for css only solution?

Comment: I thought an easy hack using css would solve the problem. But I might be wrong. So no, alternative solution using javascript would also works (I am using react). Are you implying implement a scroll bar function using js?

Comment: why you don't disable the form scroll and make the menu fixed and add zindex then it will fix the problem,or with js you can change the height of the form from screen height because the menu is absolute positioned